# Capturing partial URL's to make FileName

Tags: android, webview, download, filepath

I need help for this. The path for my URL is something like this

> http://www.sample.com/ebooks/27827.epub.images

But i when i use the below codes it shortens it to

> 27827.epub.images

I need fileName to become

> 27827.epub

without the .images

```
String path = url.getPath();
String idStr = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

String fileName = idStr;


InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/" + fileName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give a complete answer, you need to define the possible formats for the URL. If you can assume it always ends with ".images", simply cut that part off,

```
fileName = idStr.replace(".images", "");
```

If it's the case that you always want to cut off the trailing "." and anything after it, you can do,

```
fileName = idStr;
int idx = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
if (idx != -1) {
  fileName = fileName.subString(0, idx); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for the last '.' in the string and then strip anything after it

Comment: thanks but, could you please provide me the code? Your help is very much appreciated